# Error: ordered comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'int **')

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop, return, malloc

> ft_ultimate_range.c:14:13: error: ordered comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'int **') [-Werror]
>
> "while (min < range)"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ft_ultimate_range(int **range, int min, int max)
{
    int size;
    int i;

    size = max - min;
    if (min >= max)
        return (0);
    *range = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    i = 0;
    while (min < range)
    {
        range[0][i] = min;
        i++;
        min++;
    }
    return (size);
}

int main()
{
    int one = 2;
    int two = 6;
    int number = 3;
    int *pt1 = &number;
    int **pt2 = &pt1;


    printf("%i\n", ft_ultimate_range(pt2, one, two));
    return (0);
}
```

What is error?

Comment: What do you expect `while (min < range)` to do?

Comment: Try `while (min < range)` --> `while (min < max)`

Comment: @chux Thankss !! Run !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if range is a 2d array, you are comparing an int(min) with whole 2d array int**(range) which is invalid.

```
//while (min < range) //min is integer, range is 2d array. comparison is invalid. 
while (min < range[i][0]) //compare with value of 2darray instead
```